# How to write a regular expression to match a set of values?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if my string holds following value or not:

For samples:

- 4850324810111981066060
- 50104810111981066060

My condition is

```
48-57(1 or more time)32(or)10(or)13(then)48(then)32(or)10(or)13(then)111981066060
```

**Question:** How to write regular expression for above condition. Parenthesis indicate occurrence.

Comment: can you provide some samples?

Comment: what would your regex match or don't match?

Comment: as you have 32, 10 and 13 chars recurrently, these aren't ASCII character codes, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(4[8-9]|5[0-7])+(32|10|13)48(32|10|13)111981066060`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) - it allows you to build and test your regexs, and creates a C# code snippet or a .NET assembly for you right away. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:4[89]|5[0-7])+(?:32|10|13)48(?:32|10|13)111981066060");
regex.Match(string);
```

Didnt test though!

Answer (score 0):

You can test regular expressions in .NET online using **[Nregex](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
(48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57)+(32|10|13)48(32|10|13)111981066060
```

**EDIT:** Just saw [Paul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851937/how-to-write-regular-expression-in-c/1851951#1851951) and this really can be shortened to

```
(4[89]|5[0-7])+(32|10|13)48(32|10|13)111981066060
```

Only difference between hos and mine approaches is: he doesn't keeps grouping information (as that isn't required) and I don't care for ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following and see if you need to make imprevements

```
(4[89]|5[0-7])+(32|10|13)48(32|10|13)111981066060
```

it might be better to split up into fields and check those fields against your business logic instead of relying on a static regexp like the above.